# I am trying to split a word containing capital letters in it. It fails when repetitive occurrence founded

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I am trying to split a word containing capital letters in it. It fails when repetitive occurrence founded.

```
function spltToWord(prm){
    var spltedAr=[];
    var tmp = prm.match(/[A-Z]+/g).forEach(function(e,i,a){
        if(i!= a.length-1){
            spltedAr.push(prm.substring(prm.indexOf(a[i]),prm.indexOf(a[i+1])));
        }
        else{
            spltedAr.push(prm.substring(prm.indexOf(a[i])));
        }
    });
    return spltedAr.join(" ").trim();
}
```

but fails in these situations

original word : output (desired output)

EANListElement : EANListElement(EAN List Element),

CurrencyCode : CurrencyCode (Currency Code),

UPCListElement : UPCList Element (UPC List Element),

IsEligibleForTradeIn : Is Eligible For IsEligibleFor IsEligibleForTradeIn (Is Eligible For Trade In)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `string.split` and doing splitting according to the boundary which exists before an uppercase letter which was followed  by a lowercase letter.

```
string.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/)
```

Example:

```
> "EANListElement".split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/)
[ 'EAN', 'List', 'Element' ]
> "UPCListElement".split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/)
[ 'UPC', 'List', 'Element' ]
```

Comment: Cool, it worked for me. But just egar to know by applying my algorithm is there any way to resolve this error?

Comment: those scenario my algorithm fails in